# conditional assignment for matrices

Tags: matlab, python-3.x

I have 2 binary 1xM matrices, let's say A and B:

```
A = [0 1 1 0 1 1 1]
B = [0 0 0 1 1 0 0]
```

I want to find matrix C such that the value of B is conditioned with the value of A.

i.e. `C = B(A)` in Matlab.

Is there any function in Python which generates C using this conditional assignment?

Comment: what do you mean "is conditioned"? What is your expected output here? Because that Matlab example `C=B(A)` would just be an error...

Comment: Here i want to find the probability(B/A). I planned to generate matrix c where only those portions of b are considered where the corresponding values of a values to some logical values.a =

   1   1   1   1   1

>> b= rand(1,5)>0.4
b =

   1   0   1   1   0

>> c=b(a)
c =

   1   0   1   1   0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

Your second example, in MATLAB can be handled like this:

```
a = [1 1 1 1 1] 
b = rand(1,5)
a(b<0.4) = 0

a =

     1     1     1     1     1


b =

    0.0975    0.2785    0.5469    0.9575    0.9649


a =

     0     0     1     1     1
```

And the same in Python:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
B = np.array([0.0975,    0.2785,    0.5469,    0.9575,    0.9649])
b = B <0.4
A[b] = 0
print A


[0 0 1 1 1]
```

---

As you mentioned if both arrays are binaries it sounds like you want to use the `A` array as a logical array that tells you which members of `B` to select (True or False). In that sense, in MATLAB you do something like this:

```
C = A(B==1)
```

or

```
C = A(logical(B))
```

Then the result would be the elements of `A` where `B` is `True`

```
 C = 
   [0 1]
```

In Python, the same can be done using Masking:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1])
B = np.array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0])

b = B == 1
print A[b]
```

that would also result in:

```
[0 1]
```